# Verification for register does not work java

Tags: java

```
   String email = email_register_txt.getText();
   String username = username_register_txt.getText();

   Statement stmt = db_connection.connect().createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE username=' "+username+" ' OR user_email=' "+email+" ' ";

    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    if(res.next()) {

        if(res.getString("username").equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(registerPanel, "The username has already been already registered!");

        } else if (res.getString("user_email").equalsIgnoreCase(email)) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(registerPanel, "This email address has already been already registered!");
    }

} else { ...
```

Either of those error message appear when i enter the username/email who has already been inserted into the database.
My register work but I think the verify part may be missing something?

Comment: And your problem is...

Comment: IT does not work when I enter a user name that already exist, it does nothing...

Comment: Did you verify that your query returns any rows?

Comment: I can register fine it does not work only when I enter a already existing username..., if only the error msg appear which it does not!

Comment: pls check your first record as you are using if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obviously not showing all the pertinent code or you simply have neglected to place the needed code into your method that should make this work.

A [ResultSet](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-result-sets.htm) is basically a collection of results from your query which you need to iterate through to access all results from that query. A **while** loop is widely used as the means to iterate through all the results contained within a result set object. I see nowhere in your code where you have declared a ResultSet Object but yet you are trying to utilize one. Perhaps try something like this:

```
String email = email_register_txt.getText();
String username = username_register_txt.getText();

try {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("...your jdbc connection string...");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE username = ? OR user_email = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, username);
    stmt.setString(2, email);

    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();

    // Utilize a boolean Flag to indicate whether 
    // or not the User is registered.
    boolean registered = false; 
    while (res.next()) {
        if(res.getString("username").equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(registerPanel, 
                    "The username has already been already registered!");
            registered = true;
            break; // Get out of the loop. No more need for it.
        }
        else if(res.getString("user_email").equalsIgnoreCase(email)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(registerPanel, 
                    "This email address has already been already registered!");
            registered = true;
            break; // Get out of the loop. No more need for it.
        }
    }

    // Do what needs to be done if User is NOT registered.
    if (!registered) {
        ...............................
        ...............................
    }
    res.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close(); //Close the DB connection
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will notice the use of the [PreparedStatement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_prepared_statement.htm) Class. There are a number of benefits for using this class:

1) **PreparedStatement** allows you to write dynamic and parametric queries.

2) **PreparedStatement** is faster than **Statement** in Java.

3) **PreparedStatement** prevents **SQL Injection Attacks** in Java

Read more about [Why to use Prepared Statements in Java here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/why-use-preparedstatement-in-java-jdbc.html#ixzz4pSqh8cJW).

Comment: it work, i believe it was the boolean thing and the while loop that were missing for it to work properly. yes i declare my resultset and preparestatement on top of the page, that why you could not see it